# React sends a empty JSON object on PUT

Tags: json, reactjs, rest, axios

I'm trying to send a PUT request to a REST server that I have created, but no matter what I do the JSON object that is sent is empty. I have tried the server in Postmaster and it works as intended, so the problem must be with the React application.

This is the function that send the request:

```
    handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const newBrand = this.state.brand
        newBrand.description = this.state.editorState.getCurrentContent().getPlainText()
        const json = JSON.stringify(newBrand)
        console.log(json)
        axios.put(`http://localhost:8080/BackendWiki/api/brands/${this.props.brandName}`, {json})
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res);
                console.log(res.data);
            })
    }
```

The son object that's printed to the console looks like this:

```
{"id":56,"created":1597255927810,"updated":1597255927810,"links":[{"href":"http://localhost:8080/BackendWiki/api/brands/rolex","rel":"self","action":"GET"},{"href":"http://localhost:8080/BackendWiki/api/brands/rolex","rel":"self","action":"DELETE"},{"href":"http://localhost:8080/BackendWiki/api/brands/rolex","rel":"self","action":"PUT"}],"name":"Rolex","founded":0,"founder":null,"ceo":null,"headQuarters":null,"description":"more, more, more","text":[]}
```

I have implemented a get request that works like it should, which looks like this:

```
    componentDidMount() {
        Axios.get("http://localhost:8080/BackendWiki/api/brands/")
            .then(res => {
                const brands = res.data;
                this.setState({brands})
            })
    }
```

Heres the code that handles the PUT request:

```
 @PUT
    @Path("/{name}")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response updateBrand(@PathParam("name") String name, Brand updateBrand) {
        System.out.println(updateBrand);
        Brand oldBrand = brandDAO.getBrandByName(name.replaceAll("-", " "));
        if (oldBrand != null) {
            updateBrand.setId(oldBrand.getId());
            brandDAO.update(updateBrand);
            return Response
                    .status(200)
                    .entity(brandDAO.getBrandById(updateBrand.getId()))
                  //  .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
                    .build();
        } else {
            return Response
                    .status(404)
                    //.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
                    .build();
        }
    }
```

I don't get any error messages either, so I'm a bit confused as to why the PUT does not work. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: have you tried sending it without stringifying?

Comment: You're converting your json to a string, but then putting it in an object with `{json}`. Something is wrong here. does your api accept form encoded data, or json? you probably either need to form encode it, or just send the json body without stringifying

Comment: I get the same result when I don't use stringify. My API accepts json, I have updated the question with the code that handles the request. Can it be that I need to set a header in the request to specify that it's json?